# Grouping model objects in Django

Tags: python, django, database-design

I have an app with 2 models: `Product` and `Photo`, each of which corresponds to a MySQL table (drived by MyISAM).

`Product` is a `ForeignKey` field of `Photo`. Several `Photo` objects may share a single `Product` object.

Now, the question: I need `Photo` objects to be further subgrouped into sets representing the same real world object (instance of a product) photographed from different aspects. I want to differentiate this different real world objects, but still have them all connected to their `Product` object.

What's the best way to group the photos in terms of efficiency of both database querying and manual data input?

---

Thanks to @shawnwall, more ideas:

- Maybe `Product` should be connected not to individual `Photo` objects but to sets of photos.
- There should be a set for each real-word object, even if there's only 1 photo of it now.
- The set should be represented by an ID field on the `Photo` table, common between certain `Photo` objects and a `Product` object. (What kind of field is that?)

Comment: Can you paste in your current model definitions for the two objects?

Comment: @shawnwall, sure: http://codepad.org/Qok7S1pK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your approach is decent so far. I considered a manytomany field from product to photos, but it doesn't sound like its needed. You could add an 'aspect' column that relates to a list of 'choices' on the photo table. Also remember django will let you query both ways:

```
Photo.objects.filter(product__id=1)
```

or

```
Product.objects.filter(photo__id=2)
```

You can also access them through instances:

```
photo.product
```

or

```
product.photo_set
```